# Calculus -as X approaches O or infinity

Tags: calculus, limits

What would $\lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty}  3^{1/x}$ be? I'm really confused between $\frac{1}{-\infty}$ infinity and $\frac{1}{\infty}$. Also what if the limit is taken as $x$ approaches negative zero.

Comment: in this case, it doesn't matter if x goes to negative or positive infinity, 1 divided by that gives $-0$ or $+0$ and HERE, with base 3 the answer is $1$. The problem would be much more interesting what happens if $x$ approaches $0$ from either side. That does make a big difference!

Answer (score 0):

$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{1}{x}=0 \quad (1)$

This means as $x$ gets arbitrarily large in the positive direction the fraction $\frac{1}{x}$ gets arbitrarily small. Note that infinity is not a number which $x$ approaches, rather, Eq (1) is the notation that means let $x$ get arbitrarily large.Similiarly, $$\lim_{x\to -\infty}\frac{1}{x}=0 \quad (2)$$ means let $x$ get arbitrarily large in the negative direction.

Thus, $$\lim_{x\to-\infty}{3^{\frac{1}{x}}}=3^0 = 1$$

Regarding, your second question, I think you mean letting $x$ approach zero from the left side (as negative zero is just zero).Well, $$\lim_{x \to -0}{\frac{1}{x}} =  -\infty$$ by which we mean the expression $\frac{1}{x}$ gets arbitrarily large in the negative direction. Then,

$$\lim_{x \to -0}{3^{\frac{1}{x}}}=0$$